# Thread processing in java

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I am trying to design an efficient threading component for my project. my java code is reading 1000s of feed files using threads( thread pool). each file has 1000s of rows and row could be duplicated in multiple files. There are possibilities that half of the information available in one file and another half in some other file ( but we have our own business logic to correlate). We are reading these files and insert into the database. currently, we inserting one by one ( using a lock to  insert into DB just to make sure only one row per record from all files) but I wanted to design such that lock should be done on the record properties say, emp data should be sequential and company data together sequential but emp and company data should go in parallel. Another issue we don't know the record type, it is dynamic. Tomorrow I might get salary data.

Comment: What is the specific question you would like us to help you with?

Comment: I am not sure how can I design component which can take lock based on object property value.

Comment: "...each file has 1000s of rows and row could be duplicated in multiple files..." Back in the old days, we would have sorted and merged those files and _then_ ingested them into the database.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Right now your question is too specific and is hard to follow.  Can you take a step back and make it more generic?  Either that or can you show some of the entities involved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting to operate on a bunch of data in parallel, and have different operations lock shared locks while they run.

Here's an example of this: store multiple locks in a map which you look up with some mapping you draw from your data (e.g. employee data or company data).

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class MultipleLocks {

    static Map<Operation.Type, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Collection<Operation> operations = new HashSet<>();
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.ALPHA, () -> System.out.println(1)));
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.ALPHA, () -> System.out.println(2)));
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.ALPHA, () -> System.out.println(3)));
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.BRAVO, () -> System.out.println(4)));
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.BRAVO, () -> System.out.println(5)));
        operations.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.CHARLIE, () -> System.out.println(5)));

        operations.parallelStream().forEach(operation -> {
            Lock lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(operation.type, type -> new ReentrantLock());
            lock.lock();
            operation.op.run();
            lock.unlock();
        });
    }

    static class Operation {
        enum Type {
            ALPHA, BRAVO, CHARLIE;
        }

        Type type;
        Runnable op;

        Operation(Type alpha, Runnable op) {
            type = alpha;
            this.op = op;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These operations are static. In my case, I don't know what data will come. I need to perform an operation on a similar type with the lock without having knowledge of what data is coming.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you post a small sample of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I don't have any code yet. Just imagine, I have x number of threads reading files and storing data in DB. To avoid multiple rows for the same item, we can serialize the insert( correlate row for the same item in memory ). This will slow down my inserts, so I wanted to take conditional lock bases on row identifier( in your case may be by operation type).

Comment: Sounds like you're on to the right track - you'd have a map of row identifiers to locks.